# why react-helmet-async is not working in app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application, when I am using Helmet to show the title of the browser dynamically, the page in which I am using the CODE Like -

```
 **<Helmet>      
<title>Login</title>   
</Helmet>**
```

then my page is getting disappeared Mode, nothing error is showing. In my react app I installed the react-helmet-async and I also imported the config ----
**import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";**
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please add more details to clearly understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap the APP in index.js by HelmetProvider and also import HelmetProvider. You can follow following lines of code:
index.js:

```
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<HelmetProvider>
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
</HelmetProvider>
);
```